# Lucene.Net: Search for a phrase using all inflected word forms

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am new to Lucene and I got stuck on how to combine searching for a phrase with searching for all inflected forms, like this:

"(quick|quicker) brown (fox|foxes)"

but this is not a valid query syntax.

Or any other suggestions on how to search for a phrase using all possible word forms?

Answer (score 0):

Change your analyzer to one that uses a [stemmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). [EnglishAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html), for instance.

Comment: A have thought about using a stemmer. The problem is that it would leave only root forms in the index, but would like to allow a user to search for exact words as well.